# How to refresh the browser page in a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I have a lightning component which handles a event and performs subsequent dml operations. Once this is done, a toast message is displayed (success/ error etc.) 
I want to refresh the entire browser window after this. I tried force:refreshView, but it just refreshes the component.

Any help? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use standard JS way -

```
window.location.reload()
```

Please note you have to make a property call from **window** object obligately (not just location.reload()) because Lightning LockerService treats the global namespace differently and the window object there is a special wrapper around original one.

Have tested it inside one of my Lightning components under Chrome and IE 11 - it works.

---

As an alternative (but not recommended), you can try the old Lightning way with refresh event:

```
$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

documentation is here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm

But from my experience, it works smoothly not everywhere,
e.g. I encountered the next issue in one of the places:

```
Uncaught Action failed: one:recordHomeFlexipage$controller$refresh 
[Cannot read property 'Qi' of null]
```

and there is no documentation entries for this event on API v43 and v44.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect it on success as [described here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm):

```
navigateToMyComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:myComponent",
        componentAttributes: {
            contactName : component.get("v.contact.Name")
        }
    });
    evt.fire();
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this. Thanks for your comment btw. I navigated to the sObject record. However it doesnt refresh the page and hence I cannot see the updated case record post the dml operation. I still have to manually refresh the browser page. :)

Comment: The referred link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.reload()` in the lightning web component to refresh the page.

```
location.reload()
```